# Unity 3D realistic accelerometer control

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, accelerometer

How do we achieve a control similar to this game?
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fridgecat.android.atiltlite&hl=en

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with builtin physics:

1. create a level from some simple scaled cubes (don't forget the ground).

[image: example of a simple level]

2. add the ball - a sphere, then and add a `RigidBody` to it. Set a constraint on the rigidbody - check freeze position y (or it will be able to jump out of the level if you put the device upside down).
3. add this script anywhere on the scene (for example to the camera):

   ```
   using UnityEngine;

   public class GravityFromAccelerometer : MonoBehaviour {

       // gravity constant
       public float g=9.8f;

       void Update() {
           // normalize axis
           Physics.gravity=new Vector3( 
               Input.acceleration.x,
               Input.acceleration.z,
               Input.acceleration.y
           )*g;
       }

   }
   ```

   or if you want the physics to just affect this one object, add this script to the object and turn off it's rigidbody's affected by gravity:

   ```
   using UnityEngine;

   [RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
   public class ForceFromAccelerometer : MonoBehaviour {

       // gravity constant
       public float g=9.8f;

       void FixedUpdate() {
           // normalize axis
           var gravity = new Vector3 (
               Input.acceleration.x,
               Input.acceleration.z,
               Input.acceleration.y
           ) * g;

           GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce (gravity, ForceMode.Acceleration);
       }

   }
   ```

And now you have working ball physics. To make the ball behave as you'd like, try to play with the rigidbody properties. For example, change the drag to something like 0.1.

Comment: So, we are changing the global gravity? I want the accelerometer only affect the ball's movement., there will be other obstacle that also need rigidbody.,

Comment: Well, this is the way these games work in real life physics, but for your convenience I've added another version that supports only one object.