# Use Accelerometer for Roll-a-ball Movement

Tags: unity-game-engine, accelerometer

I'm working on maze game for Android in Unity 5.1.1f1 and I have troubles with controlling my ball with accelerometer. At start I tried:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject sphere;
    public Camera camera;
    public float speed=200;

    private Rigidbody myRigidBody;

    void Start()
    {
        myRigidBody = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }


    void FixedUpdate() 
    {
        float moveH = Input.acceleration.x;
        float moveV = -Input.acceleration.z;

        Vector3 move = new Vector3 (moveH, 0.0f, moveV);
        myRigidBody.AddForce (move * speed*Time.deltaTime);
    }   
}
```

But the ball is not moving as it should. Then I tried another solution. But my ball still doesn't move right. It seems like it's sometimes hard to move left/right/forward/backward, also it's possible my ball will rotate in the opposite direction.

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {


    public float speedAc = 10;

    //accelerometer
    private Vector3 zeroAc;
    private Vector3 curAc;
    private float sensH = 10;
    private float sensV = 10;
    private float smooth = 0.5f;
    private float GetAxisH = 0;
    private float GetAxisV = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        ResetAxes();
    }

    //accelerometer
    void ResetAxes(){
        zeroAc = Input.acceleration;
        curAc = Vector3.zero;
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {

        curAc = Vector3.Lerp(curAc, Input.acceleration-zeroAc, Time.deltaTime/smooth);

        GetAxisH = Mathf.Clamp(curAc.x * sensH, -1, 1);
        GetAxisV = Mathf.Clamp(-curAc.z * sensV, -1, 1);

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (GetAxisH, 0.0f, GetAxisV);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(movement * speedAc);
    }       
}
```

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered this one in another SO question: [Unity 3D realistic accelerometer control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332871/unity-3d-realistic-accelerometer-control/29376284#29376284) - you've got two variants of control there, just copy the one you find fit.

If you're having more problems, ask.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I tried your two solutions. My ball is rolling through maze quite good but the problem is it still got stuck somehow when there's a wall on two sides of the ball when it stops. In that moment it's hard to get it move again directly backwards. But if I tilt device little away from the wall and then backwards, then everything works great. It looks like my walls somehow slowing down the ball because something similar happens when the ball is rolling forwards next to the wall. It's possible to change that?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot with your colliders highlighted (select the objects)?

Comment: What if you make one long collider and not many close to each other? Does this help? Also, did you use any physical material, or just went on with the default that comes with rigidbody?

Comment: I've tested another level I made before in Blender, there I created 3D model of whole maze with not too much faces. I have defined two materials in Unity, one for maze (Dynamic Friction:1, Static Friction: 1, Bounciness: 0, Friction Combine: Average, Bounce Combine: Average, Friction Direction 2: 0, 0, 0, Dynamic Friction 2:0) and one for my ball (Dynamic Friction: 0, Static Friction: 0, Bounciness: 0.5, Friction Combine: Average, Bounce Combine: Average, Friction Direction 2: 0, 0, 0, Dynamic Friction 2: 0, Static Friction: 0). With 3D model of maze my ball works in Unity as it should! :)